# WiFi networks detected, but not connecting

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, realtek-wireless

I am new to Linux, and have just installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on my PC. I am having trouble connecting to the internet. I have an usb Wifi adapter (tp-link tl-wn8200nd). It identifies the networks, but it is unable to connect to them.

My laptop (running windows) connects fine to the networks. Also, when I take the adapter and plug it in my laptop, it connects fine to the network.

Also, On the PC, when I ran windows, I had no problem connecting to the internet with this adapter. So I guess the problem is the operating system.

I don't have any other options as to how to connect the PC to the internet. 
HELP!

EDIT:
This is copy-pasted from the terminal, for lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 003: ID 7392:7622 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd 
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 002: ID 1058:1140 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Book Essential USB3.0
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0100  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1a81:1004 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Note that the "Edimax" refers to a temporary WiFi adapter (which works fine), not the one that I'm trying to fix (which is TPLINK).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for the Linux driver on the manufacturer's website. If you're having trouble finding or installing the driver, go to the software center and install Windows Wireless Drivers. Save the windows driver (not exe file, but a folder including all driver files) to an appropriate location. Launch Windows Wireless Drivers and load the windows driver (inf file) and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

There is no Linux driver on the manufacturer website. 

I have tried installing Windows Wireless Drivers via the software center, but after installing I can't seem to be able to run it. It doesn't appear when I press the super key and write "Windows Wireless Drivers". Maybe that's a different problem. Can I somehow remove the previous (and probably corrupted in some sense) installation and re install not from the software center?

Comment: @IdanPerl You need to remove all you tried to install for that.

Comment: I removed and re-installed, still doesn't work

Comment: I am posting another answer to this question, so read that carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a driver this way. Tun in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms linux-firmware
```

Your adapter is Realtek rtl8192cu [2357:0100].

If this driver does not work (maybe this product ID is not listed in the driver), you can try another one, where it is listed for sure. Run

```
sudo apt-get remove rtl8192cu-dkms
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

and reboot.

Standalone rtl8192cu works better in most cases, but some PIDs need adding. I will take care of that, when I have time.

Comment: Just tried it, also doesn't work. Something definitely changed,  suddenly I'm asked for the password, but it still doesn't connect.

Comment: @IdanPerl I am updating the answer. Did you reboot?

Comment: I rebooted, yes

Comment: @Try another driver.

Comment: Did that too (and rebooted). Doesn't work :(

Comment: @IdanPerl What is encryption in the router?

Comment: I... don't know. How do I find out? My laptop is (wirelessly) connected to it if it helps.